# GAE Application serializing Long as String. How to change it?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java-8, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have a GAE application configured with Cloud Endpoints Framework v2 and Java 8. It is working well for the services already defined there.

I have a method to define a new service. Looks like this:

```
@ApiMethod(httpMethod = "get", path = "/operations/mine")
public UserOperationsResponse getOperationsForUser(User user) {
    return operationsService.
        getOperationsByUserId(user.getUserId());
}
```

This is the design of `UserOperationsResponse` class:

```
public class UserOperationsResponse {
    private List<Long> items;

    public UserOperationsResponse() {
    }

    public UserOperationsResponse(List<Long> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public List<Long> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
}
```

The method works as expected and retrieves the data. However, when I go to postman and test the service, I get this response:

```
{
    "items": [
        "4676209648599040"  // <-- string
    ]
}
```

How can I get an array of numbers rather than an array of strings in the response?

Comment: This is by design for languages like JavaScript where int64s can't be accurately represented numerically (due to using doubles for everything).

Comment: @saiyr could you provide references for that?

Comment: Could you please provide the command that you're running when retrieving the response in Postman?

Answer (score 0):

From:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/users/User.html#getFederatedIdentity--

```
java.lang.String    getUserId()
```

Returns an opaque string that uniquely identifies the user represented by this User object.

I think you want:

```
user.getKey().getId();
```

Comment: I know that. Just to note, that's the argument for another method to retrieve data in form of `List<Long>` and return it wrapped in an `UserOperationsResponse` object.

Comment: Going to have to go up the chain to where you call `UserReservationResponse()` vs.`UserOperationsResponse()`

Comment: Sorry, typo in the question. Now it's fixed.